# How do I check for an item on the firebase server?

Tags: react-native

How do I check for a link?That is, I need to check if there is a path :

```
.ref("users/" + this.state.name  + "/events/" + this.state.eventname);
```

Specifically, the existence of the item : **this.state.event**

If the element does not exist then:

```
this.setState({ isHidden: true });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*I believe you dont need to do this to accomplish what you want.*

You can make a call to try and fetch the URL and if it does not exist then the fireFunc just wont run. If it does then you could have a completion block which checks if it is a success of fail and do what you want then.

**Something like:**

```
 user?.updatePassword(updatedPassword, completion: {  error in
     if error != nil {
       print("Error. Show error in current viewController")
     } else {
       print("Login Successful, go to next viewController")
     }
  })
```